# Multiple POST requests with rest-assured got 500 error on second

Tags: java, rest-assured

I need to send many requests one by one. I have a code:

```
   public void sendRestRequest(String xmlFile){

        try{
            String myRequest = generateStringFromResource(xmlFile);
            given().auth().basic(prop.getProperty("restLogin"), prop.getProperty("restPassword"))
                    .contentType("application/xml")
                    .body(myRequest.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                    .when()
                    .post(prop.getProperty("restURL"))
                    .then().
                    assertThat().statusCode(200).and().
                    assertThat().body("status", equalTo("UPLOADED"));
            }
        catch (Exception e){ LOG.error(String.valueOf(e)); }
    }

public static String generateStringFromResource(String path) throws IOException {
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));
    }
```

I can successfully create first request. But in the second one I have 500 status code instead of 200. And such error message:

```
at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure.validate(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:483)
        at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure$validate$1.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.validateResponseIfRequired(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:655)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
        at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:123)
        at io.restassured.specification.ResponseSpecification$statusCode$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.statusCode(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:131)
        at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.statusCode(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:119)
```

May be anybody has ideas? I guess that should be some connection closer or something like this.

Comment: So, this is an excerpt of the client code and part (missing an important bit on the first line) of an exception on client java side, correct? And the problem is that the server returns status 500 (internal server error) in its http response. Do you think you have given us enough of the right information to produce anything useful?

Comment: short version: the server is telling you that something went wrong on its end, you will not find the reason on the client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server side the problem was with xml file, but it is strange, because there are no  problems with the same file if I send it first time. After some attempts, I decided to use different approach which works great:

```
public void sendRestRequest(String xmlFile) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("configuration.properties");
        prop.load(fis);
        try {
            URL url = new URL(prop.getProperty("restURL"));
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", prop.getProperty("basic"));

            String input = generateStringFromResource(xmlFile);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(input.getBytes());
            os.flush();

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
            StringBuilder responseStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String output;
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {responseStrBuilder.append(output);}

            conn.disconnect();

            JSONObject result = new JSONObject(responseStrBuilder.toString());
            Assert.assertEquals(result.getString("status"), "UPLOADED");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error(String.valueOf(e));
        }
    }
```